# Magento 2 - Add image to category programmatically

Tags: magento2, category, rest-api

I'm trying to create a web service rest to add an image to category, but I can't find the Model method that allow to do this.

I'm looking for something like

> addImage of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor

for the category.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For category, by default, seem that we cannot do the same, however, we can add the image like this:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category **/

$category->isObjectNew(true);
$category->setId(5)
    ->setName('Category 1.1.1')
    ->setParentId(4)
    ->setPath('1/2/3/4/5')
    ->setLevel(4)
    ->setAvailableSortBy('name')
    ->setDefaultSortBy('name')
    ->setIsActive(true)
    ->setPosition(1)
    ->setCustomUseParentSettings(0)
    ->setCustomDesign('Magento/blank')
    ->setThumbnail('media/catalog/category/test.jpg')
    ->save();
```

With API (not yet test)

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $category **/

$category->get($categoryId)
         ->setThumbnail('media/catalog/category/test.jpg');
         ->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Khoa, the path on setThumbnail method is yuor local path or the image have to be uploaded before on magento?

Comment: The image have to be uploaded before on Magento.

Comment: This is a problem, because I'm creating a webservice to allow third part to upload the images and data of categories. So the method need also to upload the image from custom path

Comment: I got the soluction, for categories to upload images it's only necessary put them in the right folder and set the name on image attribute.

Comment: Yeah! You can edit my answer or answer your own question.